# Opengl Es 1.1 Setting Different Transformations For Different Parts of Array

Tags: opengl-es

I have the following code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(.03f * state, 0.0f, 0.0f);

state = 0;

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, LOC);

glPopMatrix();
```

I pop the matrix at the end so that I can apply a different transformation to a different part of the array. The problem is, when `glPopMatrix()` is present at the end of this code, the object drawn keeps wiggling instead of moving like its supposed to.

Note: State is set somewhere out of the loop and does not cause the draw function to stop working (as the function works without glPopMatrix()).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, and you did not supply enough information. From what I can see though, `state` never changes, since you set it to `0` in the display loop. Thus, the object will not move.